# Ubuntu crashing after clicking "Show Applications" button

Tags: 18.04, amd-graphics, crash

Using 18.04 LTS. When i click "Show Applications" on the toolbar, it pulls up all of my apps, but then the screen goes black and it crashes shortly after. It does so regardless of whether i click any apps, and at varying times of how long i have had the screen pulled up. Where do i start?

Additional Information:
I forgot to add, this issue is true when running Ubuntu using Wayland. Running with the default setting results in random crashes instead of this very specifically timed one. I then assumed this to be a graphics driver issue, but my pc boots to a black screen after installing amd-gpu-pro drivers. Not sure what else to try at this point.

Comment: Do you have any GNOME extensions enabled? If so, what happens if you disable them?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried disabling them, the problem still persists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have (finally) found the fix for this issue through my own research. I am posting my solution in case someone, somewhere, has a similar issue.

Finding no real evidence of an issue after scouring crash logs, i determined that the issue had to be related to my graphics adapter or drivers. By researching that, I found this to be a quite common issue for Ubuntu users with a r9 390 GPU. I tried and applied many various fixes, but found one using dpm-query to solve this issue completely. It seems as though the issue is related to the power-saving settings of the card, and can be solved by changing them to high and battery settings to performance.

I have made a writeup and script to apply this upon boot on my github: https://github.com/justinlautner/Ubuntu-BlackScreen-Fix.